# Как создать новый пустой Excel лист?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Задавал данный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206854/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-excel-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3), отметили как дубликат, хотя там используется DataFrame, который в любом случае создает не пустой лист.

То есть, если в DataFrame положить `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`, то да, создастся такой лист, но в любом случае появятся подписи к данным:

```
  0 1
0 1 2
1 3 4
```

Оставить бы хотя бы это:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Если нельзя просто создать и сохранить пустой лист.

Comment: как следует из комментариев к ответу, то, что изложено в вопросе, никакого отношения к проблеме, которую пытается решить автор, не имеет. а то, что сейчас в вопросе — действительно дубликат.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [append_df_to_excel()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
append_df_to_excel(
    filename, pd.DataFrame(a), index=False, 
    header=None, sheet_name="new")
```

Comment: Остается звездочка, то есть не сохраняет https://pastebin.com/7zXM9EA3

Comment: @Cowboyserg, какая звездочка?? Я протестировал этот ответ перед тем как запостить. У вас файл `"list1.xlsx"` уже существует в директории? Убедитесь что он не открыт в Excel в момент работы Python скрипта

Comment: Данный файл уже существует и он закрыт в Excel

Comment: @Cowboyserg, тогда все должно работать - эта функция отточена и проверена на многих версиях Python/Pandas/OpenPyxl/etc. Перегрузите комп и протестируйте опять...

Comment: Возможно я просто чего то не понимаю, но я даже заскринил шаги
https://ibb.co/XX1Pvm7 https://ibb.co/xDyLHCn https://ibb.co/xDyLHCn https://ibb.co/BttTG08

Comment: @Cowboyserg, ну дык новый лист добавился же ??

Comment: Так дело в том, что добавлялись и у меня. Просто надо чтобы это дело автоматически сохранялось, чтобы вручную не заморачиваться, собственно я это в оригинальном вопросе и писал.

Comment: @Cowboyserg, я вас не понимаю. Вот смотрите - у вас существует файл и он не открыт в Excel, потом вы запускаете Python скрипт он добавляет новый лист в Excel файл и файл все еще не открыт в Excel. Теперь вы открываете файл в Excel и видите __новый__ лист - так? Если бы файл не был сохранен - вы бы не увидели новый лист. PS у меня все замечательно работает звездочек не появляется и Excel не предлагает сохранить "измененный" файл

Comment: Смотрите, не открыт=>запускаю=>создается=>открываю экселем => вижу, да, есть новый лист => закрываю excel, он пишет "Сохранить изменения в файле?" ну и звездочка само собой. Получается лист был создан, но не был сохранен??? Как это работает??? Если же не нажимать сохранить, а просто закрыть без сохранения, а потом открыть, то вновь будет этот лист, и опять будет предложено его сохранить.

Comment: @Cowboyserg, это что-то у вас не то с этим файлом. Попробуйте создать новый Excel файл с одним листом, сохранить, закрыть Excel, запустить Python скрипт и проверить опять в Excel. У меня все отлично работает на Windows и на MacOS - извините, дальше разбирайтесь сами - я не смогу вам помочь, не имея возможности воспроизвести проблему